# mysql surpress dupe key error

Tags: php, mysql

When i need to know if something in unique before it gets inserted. i usually just attempt to insert it and then if it fails, check if the mysql_errno() is 1062. If it is i know it failed as a duplicate key and i can do whatever i need to do.

The most common place for this is in a user table. I set the email as unique as thats the "username" for logging in. Instead of running additional queries to check uniqueness when processing registration forms, i just compile the query, execute it and check for the 1062 error number. If it fails with 1062 i tell the user nicely that the email is registered and all is good.

However i recently set up a very basic MITM sql query function which gives myself and other developers on the system access to query times, a log of all the sql queries at the bottom of the page, and most importantly, a function which establishes the mysql connection to the correct database on demand (rather than having to do the connect and pass link identifiers manually).

In the sql error query log this function creates on disk, is all my duplicate entries. This obviously doesn't look good to other people seeing errors (even though there handled and expected). Is there a way of surpressing errors somehow for this but still being able to check the mysql_errno() ?

Comment: Why not searching for the key in the table and count it as duplicate when it is found? So no error will occur and you do not need to suppress it.

Comment: because thats an additional mysql query and additional code. What happens if i change the username from email to a specified username. I would have to amend the code anywhere it needs to be aware of that unique key. Performance wise i imagine it only helps by a few milliseconds, but i like to keep my query count as low as possible.

Comment: You've created a function to log things, and are complaining it's logging too much? It's your function... can't you modify it to NOT log "irrelevant" errors?

Comment: yes, i could do something like that. But thats not the point. I'd prefer to do it cleanly. Its not that i want to surpress any error, what i wanted to do was someway tell mysql that an error (or better yet, the error 1062) is an expected result. I managed to have found something in mysql docs relating to handle declaration which will allow me to set an exception handler for 1062. Which is probably what i want in this case (i wanted mysql to throw the error number, but not disclose that its an error as that leads people to believe its a bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst doing a bit of housework on my account here at SO, I thought it best to answer this with my findings so i can close it. This is basically a conclusion from my last comment above.

If you (like me) use certain error codes in mysql in your application to reduce validation queries or code (duplicate key being the most common i find). The only way to stop an error being thrown is to catch the error inside mysql and handle it. I wont go into the how-to here but a good place to get started is:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html

Note: just for the new dev's out there, also dont forget to check out "ON DUPLICATE KEY" (google it). It was something blindly suggested to me elsewhere. It doesn't fit in this example but i've used it for year's to save checking for duplicate records before insertion (it does not return a failure on duplicate entries, so its only good if you were thinking of using a duplicate error handler to instead perform an update... hence finding your way here)